# Magento2 : which event just after order has been saved

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I would like to run a function after an order has been placed.

I then tried to trigger on the event `sales_order_place_after` but at this step of the order process, order_id and item_id seems not to be defined yet.

I need to get these ids for my process. what is the next event after order_id and item_id are defined?

Thank you for your help

Comment: you can use sales_order_save_after event to get all info.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it will not do the job for me. I want to add info to the order, so when I will save it after modification, the event will be triggered again, resulting in a loop... and using checkout events won't work if an order is placed from backend or programmatically...

Comment: whats issue faced for using sales_order_place_after event?

Comment: when sales_order_place_after event is triggered, the order has not been created yet, so neither the order and items have ids.

Comment: you can use this event checkout_onepage_controller_success_action for getting order info

Comment: Have you tried with above event? please let me know if you have issue

Comment: yes, I am working on it. The idea is now to load the order from order_id in order to get the items...

Comment: Have you usedful this event checkout_onepage_controller_success_action?